# How to access custom channel extra data from iOS client

Tags: ios, swift, chat, getstream-io

Currently our backend has added a dict on `channel` object as part of the extra data, it looks something like this:

```
{
  // channel stuff from Stream
  "extra_data": {
    "custom dict": {
      "custom field": "custom value"
    }
  }
}
```

However it seems that we cannot access to that dict from the iOS client since the `channel.extraData` type is a `ChannelExtraDataCodable` which only has two properties: `name` and `imageURL`.

Is there a way to access to this custom stuff from the client side?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define your own structure conforming to ChannelExtraDataCodable and set `Channel.extraDataType` to it.

Example:

```
struct MyChannelExtraData: ChannelExtraDataCodable {
    var name: String?
    var imageURL: URL?
    var customDict: [String: String]
}

// Before you initialize the client
Channel.extraDataType = MyChannelExtraData.self
```

For more information on this, you can check the [Stream Chat's documentation about custom extra data on iOS](https://getstream.io/chat/docs/ios_custom_data/?language=swift).

Comment: yes! I was missing `Channel.extraDataType` part, thanks! Although, it seems that using a `ChannelExtraDataCodable ` we can parse the whole `channel` object instead of the `channel.extra_data`. Do you know if this is intentional? Otherwise I can report it as a bug

Comment: Great :) . I believe this is intentional, but if you have any issues, feel free to report on GitHub: https://github.com/getstream/stream-chat-swift

Comment: checked with stream team, and yes, [this](https://github.com/GetStream/stream-chat-swift/issues/541) is intentional